# GUI for an OpenCL program

Tags: visual-studio-2010, user-interface, opencl

I have to create a program in OpenCL using Visual Studio 2010 and I need to make a GUI that has some buttons to change parameters of the program. Is there any tool/language to create a MVC GUI that links to the OpenCL program?

I did GUIs in Java, but in this case I have no idea how to link the program with a GUI.

Answer (score 2):

Im assuming that you are using opencl c in visual studio. You must realize here that opencl is just an api for the c language. Hence if you need to create a GUI for your opencl code all you need to do is make a GUI in C using visual studio. I guess what you need to be searching for is an MVC based GUI in C. The GUI can be made entirely in C and the opencl implementation can be in you controller part of your MVC design.

These links might just help you get started.

[Is there any crossplatform GUI library for C language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039499/is-there-any-crossplatform-gui-library-for-c-language)

http://www.egr.msu.edu/classes/ece480/capstone/spring15/group11/doc/AppNote/ECE480_AppNotes_JoshuaFolks.pdf

[How do I create a GUI for a windows application using C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488837/how-do-i-create-a-gui-for-a-windows-application-using-c)

Comment: Thank you for the links, they're very useful. It might have seen like a silly question but I was very lost at the beginning of the implementation during the analysis and maybe a little missguided. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome, would be great if you could upvote my answer