# C - Setting Printf Coordinates without external libraries

Tags: c

I want to be able to print using x and y coordinates, using a SetCursorPosition function but as far as I can find, the proper way to do that is by using ncurses. Is it possible to do it using a default c library, like stdio or stdlib?

Comment: You can always do it the [old school way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) with control codes.

Comment: If you're in DOS/Windows, then you can use the Win32 APIs [SetCursorPos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648394(v=vs.85).aspx) or [SetConsoleCursorPosition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolecursorposition).  If you're on Linux, or want portable text-mode cursor control across Windows, Mac and *nix ... then [ncurses](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Standard C doesn’t recognize that you’d want to do that. Any solution will be platform-specific, therefore. If portability is a concern, use the features of a portable library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C Standard Library I/O functions are designed around using streams of bytes that are sent or received. Those streams of bytes are sent to some device such as a terminal or a printer or a file or a network device.  The Standard Library I/O is really oriented for text terminals, text printers, and files in which a stream of bytes or text characters is written to a device handle or read from a device handle.

About the only kind of device specific positioning of the Standard Library is for files using functions such as `ftell()` and `fseek()` as well as `rewind()` and `fgetpos()` and `fsetpos()` (see [what is difference between fgetpos/fsetpos and ftell/fseek](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348637/fgetpos-fsetpos-and-ftell-fseek) an explanation as to the differences).

The C Standard Library I/O functions do not have any terminal or printer device specific functionality such as positioning a cursor, setting text colors or text font, positioning windows, changing windows, or any of the other functionality common to Graphical User Interfaces or graphical printers (laser or inkjet).

A common work around is to use special characters, [escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence), to indicate that the text following is a command to the device itself and to then specify a command such as setting a cursor position or setting a text color. There are a number of defacto standards for these command sequences which depend on the target device.

In the old days with 80 column, 25 line terminals, most terminals supported a defacto standard with some elements of cursor positioning modeled on what was provided by the [VT-100 video terminal from Digital Equipment Corporation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100).

In order to access that cursor positioning functionality, the first C compatible libraries were developed so that a programmer could specify a cursor position and the library function would create the proper escape code sequence for the position and send it to the terminal.

[ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) is a modern version of those early libraries and is probably the most commonly used for text terminal emulation when a full blown GUI is not needed.

You might find this [List of platform-independent GUI libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_platform-independent_GUI_libraries) helpful though a GUI library may be overkill for what you actually need.

See also the various answers to [Cross Platform C library for GUI Apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018850/cross-platform-c-library-for-gui-apps)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
printf("\033[%d;%dH", row, column);
printf("text I want to print");
fflush(stdout);
```

If you'll be doing it a lot, you could encapsulate it as a function:

```
void mySetCursorPosition(int row, int column)
{
    printf("\033[%d;%dH", row, column);
}
```

This is totally nonportable, it blindly assumes your terminal (or terminal emulation window) uses the traditional ANSI escape sequences -- which these days they all do, so this is quite likely to work fine for you.

When the day comes that you want to do something higher-level or more portable, you can learn about that then.